# Pandas rolling function with shifted indices

Tags: python, pandas

The code

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4])
sr = s.rolling(3)
sr.apply(np.sum)
```

returns the series with indices [0,1,2,3,4] and values [NaN, NaN, 3, 6, 9]. Is there a quick hack, *specifically using pandas rolling functions,* so that it returns the rolling sum from the *following* 3 indices, i.e. so that the series values are [3, 6, 9, NaN, NaN]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is a shift by -2:

```
w = 3
s.rolling(w).sum().shift(-w + 1)

0    3.0
1    6.0
2    9.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `iloc[::-1]`

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4])
sr = s.iloc[::-1].rolling(3)
sr.sum().iloc[::-1]

0    3.0
1    6.0
2    9.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [numpy.roll()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html)

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4])
sr = s.rolling(3)
pd.Series(np.roll(sr.apply(np.sum),3))
```

Output:

```
0    3.0
1    6.0
2    9.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```